# JDK14 'launching a class declared in a source file' how to specify encoding

Tags: java, encoding

I know that when using `javac xxx.java` to compile source files, you can specify the source file encoding with `-encoding` But how to specify the source file encoding while using `java xxx.java`?

I am using JDK14, I can directly use `java A.java`. No need to use `javac A.java` first and then use `java A`  to run A.class

Comment: the `java` command is for running a/an (already compiled) Java program. There is no source file involved in that.

Comment: I think you should read more on `java` and `javac` commands.  we don't do `java xxx.java` but it is `java xxx`. `java` command is run on compiled class files and not on the raw source code

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose @Nithin Not necessarily true - JDK11 added the ability to run single-file programs direct from `java`, no `javac` necessary - it does it all in memory - so it's possible he's asking the right question. https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/java/tutorials/java-theory-and-practice-2/

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose @Nithin I am using JDK14, I can directly use ```java A.java```. No need to use ```javac A.java``` first and then use ```java A```  to run A.class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like based on https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330 that you might be able to specify `--encoding UTF8` or whatever you want BEFORE your source file name and it would be picked up:

> In source-file mode, any additional command-line options are processed as follows:
>
> - The launcher scans the options specified before the source file for any that are relevant in order to compile the source file. This includes: `--class-path`, `--module-path`, `--add-exports`, `--add-modules`, `--limit-modules`, `--patch-module`, `--upgrade-module-path`, and any variant forms of those options. It also includes the new `--enable-preview` option, described in [JEP 12](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/12)

Comment: ```java
D:\shared>java -encoding UTF8 A.java
Unrecognized option: -encoding
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

D:\shared>java --encoding UTF8 A.java
Unrecognized option: --encoding
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Comment: @akosm no that's what I was thinking might work - how about setting `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` (as in : `java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 A.java`)

Comment: It works!
If I want the chartset.defaultcharset () is different from the source file encoding, maybe the only way is to use javac

Comment: That seems logical - I suspect if you are getting into encodings it's going to more complex than a single-file java program anyway